# c++ deleting array in destructor

Tags: c++

so I got an object that have an array as one of the instance:

```
private:
  int arr[100]; //this is a fix array
```

when I call the destructor of the object, should I write:

```
~MyBook(){delete []arr;} //just like I did with array pointer
```

or should I write something like this

```
~MyBook(){}
```

thank you

Answer (score 4):

Did you allocate the array with `new[]`? No? Then don't use `delete[]`. It's as simple as that. It's undefined behavior to call `delete([])` on something not allocated with `new([])` respectively.

Also, don't write the destructor if you don't have to. In this case, it's not required.

Comment: @user1988385 I mean any dynamically-allocated array.

Comment: @user1988385 If this answered your question, please click the green tick on the left.

Answer (score 1):

If all you have is the array, then you don't need to provide any destructor. The compiler synthesized one will do fine. Even if you did need a destructor for other reasons, you should not attempt to call `delete[]` on the array. You should only do this for arrays allocated dynamically with `new[]`.

Comment: I got several instances (1 int, 2 std:string, 2 array)

Comment: @user1988385 you don't need to do anything about those either.

Comment: @user1988385: What does that even mean? Show the code you're asking the question about if the code you're showing isn't representative.